# Bluetooth communication b/w Android and IOT device

Tags: android, python, bluetooth

I am trying to establish Bluetooth communication between Android and IOT (intel galileo) device.

The code at IOT side (i am keeping it as a client), it will send data to android, but here one port number is hard coded. This is in python.

```
def record_transmit_to_subscriber(self, subscriber, message):
    server_addr = subscriber
    port = 6 
    client_socket = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
    try:
        client_socket.connect((server_addr, port))

        client_socket.send(message)

        client_socket.close()
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print "Unable to make connection with subscriber", subscriber
        return False
```

Now at android (server) side:

```
private static UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
try {
       BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter =    BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the applications UUID string, also used by the client code
            tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            GlobalUtils.writeLogFile("Error in BLE Listening " + e.getMessage());
        }
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    } catch (Exception e){
        GlobalUtils.writeLogFile("Exception in Accept Thread " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

I do believe there in some problem in this code, at client side it is using port number while at server side it is using uuid. can someone please rectify how to modify this code to make connection work.

Answer (score 0):

Seems You forgot to create socket and streams:

```
try {
    BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice("<MAC_address_of_your_device>");
    mSocket = bluetoothDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);

    mSocket.connect();
} catch (IOException e) {
   Log.e(TAG, "Fail connect");
}

// Get the input and output streams for BT socket
try {
    inStream = mSocket.getInputStream();
    outStream = mSocket.getOutputStream();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Fail to open socket streams");
}
```

Than You can create `Thread` for read data from `inStream` (for example `inStream.read(<data_buffer>);` and `Thread` for write data to `outStream` (for example `outStream.write(<data_buffer>); outStream.flush();`).

Comment: Did You gave `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>` permission for your App?